# Python one-liner that answers: Do any of these inputs return True for this function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Goal: Is there a built-in Python function (or one-liner) which will submit arguments to a function, but only until the function returns `True` for the first time? I would like to be able to answer the question

> "Do *any* of these inputs return `True` for this function?"

I don't particularly care about the results of the function when using those inputs.

The [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function returns `True` if any of the `iterable` items passed is `True`. The [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function applies arguments to a function and returns the results of all of those function calls.

So I'm looking for something in between the two. `any` only applies to `iterable` so is not relevant to functions (unless I want to `map` all arguments to the function); and `map` isn't exactly what I want because it executes the function on all inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) is "lazy", so will `return` as soon as the first element of `iterable` evaluates to `True`. However, in Python 2.x *, `map` builds a list of the results, applying `function` to everything in `iterable` before returning.

There is an alternative, though: [`itertools.imap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap), which returns an iterator instead of a list, restoring lazy evaluation. Once you:

```
from itertools import imap
```

Your one-liner is:

```
any(imap(function, iterable))
```

* *Note that `map` already returns an iterator [in Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map), and therefore `itertools.imap` is no longer available.*

Answer (score 2):

Use a comprehension:

```
any(func(arg) for arg in args)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the argument to `any` is a ["generator expression"](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).